# How to query mongodb for objects with common features in an array

Tags: mongodb

for example I have an object with an embedded array of strings

```
ids : ['ab','gg',kl']
```

I would like to query for the first 10 objects which share the most ids

Comment: Are you trying to find documents with embedded arrays whose elements match the elements of a specified array (i.e. matching ids: ['ab', 'gg', 'kl']), or does the exact array not matter, so long as the document shares the most ids with another document? I hope this question make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Got too long for a comment, but maybe you can't do any better anyway...

Wow, that's a hard one. Can you even do that without significant looping on a relational database? I guess you don't often have lists within a field on a relational database, so maybe that's not even a good question.

I have a feeling you're going to need to do this on the application side, looping through and storing some of the comparison analysis to get the top 10. I don't even think this is possible with map reduce/aggregation framework, unless you run map reduce for every record.

Comment: Hard -> that's why it's on Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: I agree... Don't think it's possible without looping and doing some work.

Comment: How much data are you talking about?

Comment: 100,000 objects, maybe a graph DB is better fit for this scenario ??

Comment: 100k wouldn't be imposible if you can fit it all in RAM, but yeah, maybe a graph db would be better, intersecting edges. I'm a total newbie with graph dbs, sorry I can't be more help. Maybe you should ask a new question with noe4j or something as the database.